# Passing dynamically created json url to ajax and display to html page

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask, jinja2

I am currently working on a system where the login checking of username and password is checked by a python function. If the login details are correct, it will be redirected to a profile page (which i named dashboard). My problem is that my dahsboard/profile route reutrns a json if it is a POST and has also correct login details. I want this json data to be displayed in the html file. I managed to do it but I have used the variables in my jinja template.  Although I have accomplished my goal (display the credentials in the html page), I would want it to be handled by ajax. How do I accomplish that?

Below are the codes I have tried so far (passing the data to the jinja variables)

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dashboard():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #get the username passed along with the redirect
        data1= getdatafromdb('getdata1',(request.args.get('uname'),))[0][0]
        data2= getdatafromdb('getdata2',(code,))[0]

        if 'Error' in str(data2):
            return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': data2[0][0]})



        return render_template('dashboard.html', firstname=data2[1],
                               middleinitial=data2[2],
                               lastname=data2[3],
                               contact=data2[4],
                               code=data2[5],
                               affiliation=data2[6],
                               city=data2[7])
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return True
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. Why does your code sometimes render a template and sometimes return JSON?

Comment: Im using one python function that is designed to call a stored function in postgres. My python function will also jsonify all the results since I am to talk with ajax via json. @DanielRoseman

Comment: But that doesn't explain why you sometimes render a template.

Comment: ... its the formatting ( I think ) that confuses you. that code that returns a jsonified object checks the data2 has an error. If it does, it retrns the error in jsonified format. But if it has no error, it returns a render_template along with the data (firstname, middleinitial, etc... ) this code worked on my other project. But Its only an android app getting data from json urls.. this time, I'm on the web app but Im not quiet good at it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it appears that you are running your validation process in your `/dashboard` route, which is not correct if you wish to redirect your user to that very page once their credentials are validated. Instead, you need to create your separate login method with `ajax`. First, from the `/` (home) route, render the template that contains the `input` boxes with `ajax`:

`home.html`:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <input type='text' name='username' id='username'>
   <div class='username_failed'></div>
   <input type='password' name='password' id='password'>
   <div class='password_failed'></div>
   <button type='button' class='login'>Login</button>
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.login').click(function() {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/login",
      type: "get",
      data: {username: username, password:password},
      success: function(response) {
        if (!response.status){
           $('.'+response.issue+'_failed').html('<p>'+response.message+'</p>')
        }
        else{
           window.location.replace('/dashboard'); //redirect to dashboard
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
      //Do Something to handle error
    }
   });
  });
 });
  </script>
</html>
```

Then, the login route will valid the input dynamically from the `ajax` in `home.html`. Previously, you need to create a function to validate the username and password. A possibility is to first check if they are empty, and then query the database:

```
import typing
def check_if_valid(username:str, password:str) -> typing.Dict[str, typing.Any]:
   if not username or not password:
     return {'status':False, 'issue':'username' if not username else 'password', 'message':f'{[username, password][username]} cannot be empty'}
   _username = check_valid_username_from_db(username) 
   _password = check_valid_password_from_db(username, password)
   if not _username:
     return {'status':False, 'issue':'username', 'message':'Invalid username'}
   if not _password:
     return {'status':False, 'issue':'password', 'message':'Invalid username or password'}
   return {'status':True}

@app.route('/login')
def login():
  username = flask.requests.args.get('username')
  password = flask.requests.args.get('password')
  _r = check_if_valid(username, password)
  if _r.status:
    data2= getdatafromdb('getdata2',(code,))[0]
    for i, a in enumerate(['firstname', 'middleinitial', 'lastname', 'contact', 'code', 'affiliation', 'city']):
      flask.session[a] = data2[i]
  flask.session['user_validated'] = _r.status
  return flask.jsonify(_r)
```

Now, all your user data, if the user was successfully validated, will be stored as part of the session. Now, you can create your dashboard page, first with the html for the dashboard:

`dashboard.html`:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <h1>Welcome, {{firstname}}</h1>
   <h4>Your data:</h4>
   {%for d in data%}
     <span>{{d.title}}: {{d.value}}</span>
   {%endfor%}
 </body>
</html>
```

Then, create the dashboard route with user validator:

```
def isloggedin(f):
  def wrapper(*args):
    if not flask.session['user_validated']:
      return '<p>Not logged in</p>'
    return f(*args)
  return wrapper

@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET'])
@isloggedin
def dashboard():
  from collections import namedtuple
  headers = ['firstname', 'middleinitial', 'lastname', 'contact', 'code', 'affiliation', 'city']
  data = namedtuple('data', ['title', 'value'])
  return flask.render_template('dashboard.html', firstname = flask.session['firstname'], data = [data(a, flask.session[a]) for a in headers[1:]])
```

Lastly, link all together with the home route:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
  return flask.render_template('home.html')
```